# How can I print a square block in terminal？

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, fonts

I want combination a QRcode，so I find the unicode '/u2588',it should be a square black block,But in terminal.

It can't correct display，the block become a rectangle:

[image]

So,I need escape the font?or ..

My font now :Dejavu Sans Mono
Code: python3

source code:

```
def print_cmd_qr(qrText, white=u'/u2588', black='  ', enableCmdQR=True):
    blockCount = int(enableCmdQR)
    if abs(blockCount) == 0:
       blockCount = 1
       white *= abs(blockCount)
          if blockCount < 0:
             white, black = black, white
             sys.stdout.write(' '*50 + '\r')
             sys.stdout.flush()
             qr = qrText.replace('0', white).replace('1', black)
             sys.stdout.write(qr)
             sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Is this the actual code you are running? You have "`/u2588`" but the escape's slash is backwards. (`\u2588` would be the proper escape sequence for the Unicode character "█" `FULL BLOCK`… or `\N{FULL BLOCK}`). Also, are you not printing two spaces for one color, and 1 █ for the other? This doesn't seem like it would line up.

Comment: Thank you，I  broke the the problem finally,I use the "#" escape the Unicode character "█" ，and the qrcode be able to be identified by a camera